# convert varchar parameter to datetime in sql procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Below is my procedure

```
create proc abc -- 'all','18','18','12/12/2015','','','inactive'   
@JoinedDate varchar(100),        
@LastLogin varchar(100),        
@Location varchar(100),        
@Status varchar(50) 

as        
declare @WhereCondition varchar(1000)   

set @WhereCondition=' '        
if @LastLogin !=''        
set @WhereCondition= ' and u.UpdatedDate>=' + CAST(@LastLogin as datetime) 

exec('select * from tableName where' + @WhereCondition)
```

When I am passing the parameter LastLogin it is giving me error as below:

**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

Comment: Your data types are bad. If you play fast and loose with data types in all of your code like you did in this procedure, you will continue to get errors like this. You are passing in a string (length 100?) that can not be converted to a date/time. Look at the contents of `@LastLogin` it is not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, it is possible to pass datetime as varchar paramter to dynamic sql and convert it to datetime dynamically-

Below is the way -

```
set @WhereCondition= ' and u.UpdatedDate>=convert(datetime,''' +  @LastLogin + ''', 110)'
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all capture the data in correct data type, If you are expecting a datetime value use the datetime data type for your variable.

Dont get values in varchar and then try to convert them to datetime(poor practice) , Also use parameterised dynamic sql do not concatenate variables into your dynamic sql (open doors for sql injection).

see below:

```
create proc abc -- 'all','18','18','12/12/2015','','','inactive'   
    @JoinedDate  datetime,        
    @LastLogin   datetime,        
    @Location    varchar(100),        
    @Status      varchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);   

SET @Sql = N'select * from tableName where 1 = 1 '
      + CASE WHEN @LastLogin <> ''
        THEN N' AND UpdatedDate >= @LastLogin' ELSE N'' END

 Exec sp_executesql @Sql
                   ,N'@LastLogin datetime'
                   ,@LastLogin
END
```

Comment: I just wanna know if I can convert varchar parameter to datetime. And I am not passing it as datetime because in .net code I am using same function somewhere else. so thinking to reuse it.

Comment: Shaikh Saab two wrongs dont make it right. If you have set off the wrong foot, go back and fix it before moving forward.

Comment: I am not getting how I am wrong if you can explain me about what concept I am lacking behind this it will much helpful. I mean why I can't pass datetime as varchar and convert it to datetime in sql.

Comment: When you have a variable with varchar(100) data type, what happens when a user passes a value like `'13012015'`  or `'13-01-2015'` or for that matter anything which is not a date, you'er whole proc will go tits up. Therefore use the appropriate data type so if an end user passes an invalid date value it errors out there and then (at compile time) rather then at run time.

Comment: I got the solution, it is possible to convert varchar parameter to datetime in dynamic sql please check my answer above and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't concatenate a Datetime datatype with a string.

EDITED:

Try this:

```
set @WhereCondition= ' and u.UpdatedDate>=CAST(''' + @LastLogin + ''' AS datetime)'
```

Comment: nope, this isn't working please note u.UpdatedDate is of datetime format and @LastLogin is varchar parameter

Comment: it errored out because you are concatenating a datetime value to a string.

Comment: Yes but you are creating a dynamic sql string, and then executing it.   While building the string, you have to work with strings and strings only.   It may help to CAST() the variable as a string IN the dynamic SQL, but it should be capable of doing it implicitly if it is a valid datetime string.   See my edited answer.   If it doesn't work, please post the new error message.